# Derivative of the characteristic function

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with real entries. Calculate $f'(0)$, where $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x) := \det(I_{n}-xA)$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$.

Then, the eigenvalues of $I_n - xA$ are $1-x\lambda_1, \ldots 1-x\lambda_n$.

So, $f(x) = \text{det}(I_n-xA) = (1-x\lambda_1)\cdots(1-x\lambda_n) = 1-x(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n)+O(x^2)$.

Hence, $f'(0) = -(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n) = -\text{Trace}(A)$.